How to realign viewport with world z axis after switching from trackball back to turntable?
Moving the view port around in turntable mode automatically keeps the world z axis aligned with the view port.  Switching to trackball mode allows the view port to move freely. Then switching back to turntable mode automatically keeps the view port aligned with whatever orientation you're in during the switch. Clicking on one of the green, red, or blue axis in the top corner of the view port resets the orientation so the view port is again automatically aligned with the world z axis, but it also moves the view port to a different location. How can the view port be realigned with the world z axis and not be moved?
The following script enables the user to switch between turntable and trackball using a custom menu. I think it would be much better if the view port was automatically realigned with the world z axis and didn't move to a different location when turntable mode is selected. How might that be possible?
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

bl_info = {
    "name": "Input Toggle Pie Menu",
    "author": "Syler",
    "version": (0, 0, 0, 2),
    "description": "Adds a Pie Menu to switch NDOF rotation mode in Input settings",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "3D view"
}

addon_keymaps = []

def add_hotkey():
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon

    if not kc:
        print('Keymap Error')
        return
    
    # Add keymap in 3D View
    km = kc.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(
        VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call.bl_idname, 'D', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=False)
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def remove_hotkey():
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

class VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE(Menu):
    bl_label = "Input Rotation Method"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        prefs = context.preferences
        inputs = prefs.inputs
        
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.prop(inputs, "ndof_view_rotate_method", text="NDOF Rotation Mode", expand=True)

class VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'view3d.pie_ndof_input'
    bl_label = 'Input Rotation Method Pie Menu'
    bl_description = 'Calls pie menu for NDOF rotation mode in Input settings'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE")
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call)
    add_hotkey()

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call)
    remove_hotkey()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Setting view rotation in Y axis to 0 seems to work. It's rotation is stored as a quaternion so I just convert it to euler adjust as I want and convert back.
import bpy

for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        view_rotation_euler = a.spaces[0].region_3d.view_rotation.to_euler()
        view_rotation_euler.y = 0
        a.spaces[0].region_3d.view_rotation = view_rotation_euler.to_quaternion()


Thank you for submitting this bit of code. I was able to add this plus make it so the viewport is only reset when selecting the turntable mode in the custom menu. I posted the whole new script as a separate answer.

I was able to add the code submitted by Martynas to get it working. Plus I made it so the viewport is only reset when selecting turntable in the custom menu. Just in case anyone wanted to select trackball while in trackball mode.
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

bl_info = {
    "name": "Input Toggle Pie Menu with Conditional Reset",
    "author": "Syler",
    "version": (0, 0, 0, 5),
    "description": "Adds a Pie Menu to switch NDOF rotation mode and resets view rotation if the previous mode was TRACKBALL",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "3D view"
}

addon_keymaps = []

def add_hotkey():
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon

    if not kc:
        print('Keymap Error')
        return
    
    # Add keymap in 3D View
    km = kc.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(
        VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call.bl_idname, 'D', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=False)
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def remove_hotkey():
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

class VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE(Menu):
    bl_label = "Ultimate NDOF Input Rotation Method Toggle"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        prefs = context.preferences
        inputs = prefs.inputs
        
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.operator(VIEW3D_OT_SetNDOFMode.bl_idname, text="Trackball").mode = 'TRACKBALL'
        pie.operator(VIEW3D_OT_SetNDOFMode.bl_idname, text="Turntable").mode = 'TURNTABLE'

class VIEW3D_OT_SetNDOFMode(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.set_ndof_mode"
    bl_label = "Set NDOF Mode"
    bl_description = "Sets the NDOF rotation mode and resets the view if the previous mode was TRACKBALL"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    mode: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # Get the current NDOF mode
        prefs = context.preferences
        current_mode = prefs.inputs.ndof_view_rotate_method
        
        # Set the new NDOF mode
        prefs.inputs.ndof_view_rotate_method = self.mode
        
        # Reset the view rotation if the previous mode was TRACKBALL
        if current_mode == 'TRACKBALL' and self.mode != 'TRACKBALL':
            for area in context.screen.areas:
                if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    region_3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
                    view_rotation_euler = region_3d.view_rotation.to_euler()
                    view_rotation_euler.y = 0
                    region_3d.view_rotation = view_rotation_euler.to_quaternion()
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

class VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'view3d.pie_ndof_input'
    bl_label = 'Input Rotation Method Pie Menu'
    bl_description = 'Calls pie menu for NDOF rotation mode'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE")
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_OT_SetNDOFMode)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call)
    add_hotkey()

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_MT_Input_PIE)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_OT_SetNDOFMode)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_OT_PIE_template_call)
    remove_hotkey()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Why do you create an operator just to run another operator?..

I have simply been combining different bits of code from various sources and I do not understand how to code properly. But it still works perfectly.

It doesn't seem to work in 4.3.2. Doesn't switch to trackball successfully for me.

OK, I got it, there is ndof_view_rotate_method and view_rotate_method. ndof is for trackball devices if I understand it correctly, the other one works with a mouse.

I am currently using Blender 4.0.2. This script changes the input for NDOF devices like the 3D Connexion Space Mouse. The NDOF turntable and trackball settings are in Preferences-Input-NDOF. The script can be changed to work with other devices like a regular mouse too by instead having the script switch between trackball and turntable in Preferences-Navigation-Orbit & Pan.
